# Globally disable dialog boxes for all lists?

Tags: list, dialog-framework

In SharePoint 2010, lists are set up to open modal dialog windows for item inserts and updates. I know these dialog boxes can be disabled on a list by list basis by going to List Settings -> Advanced and de-selecting the "Launch forms in a dialog" option. Is there a way to globally disable modal dialog windows for all lists, current and future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it with powershell. This might help you:

[Get-SPScripts: Change SharePoint list settings using PowerShell - Part 2: Advanced Settings](http://get-spscripts.com/2010/10/change-sharepoint-list-settings-using.html)

The article shows how to change a list's Advanced Settings programmatically, and the table row at the bottom of the article entitled 'Dialogs' gives the property you're interested in. Putting the two together would give you:

```
#Change these variables to your site URL and list name
$site = Get-SPSite http://portal
$listName = "Shared Documents"

#Walk through each site in the site collection
$site | Get-SPWeb | ForEach-Object {

#Get the list in this site
$list = $_.Lists[$listName]

#Launch forms in dialog?
#Setting this to $true will set it to 'No' in the UI
$list.NavigateForFormsPages = $true

#Update the list
$list.Update()
}

#Dispose of the site object
$site.Dispose()
```

Comment: Glad to know that, Please provide code sample which work for you. Will be helpful to others as well.